# Multiple Elements to an ArrayAdapter of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have been trying to get the password description to display in the TextView within my ListView - to no luck. Can somebody help me with what I need to do?

At this point do you think I need to use an ArrayList instead of an ArrayAdapter?

```
private static TextView mPasswordView;
private String mPassword;
private TextView mPasswordDesc;
private Button mGeneratepas;
private ListView mPasswordListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private PasswordDBHelper mHelper;
private PasswordGenerator mPasswordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mHelper = new PasswordDBHelper(this);
    mPasswordView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textPassword );
    mGeneratepas = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttonGenpas );
    mPasswordListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_password);
    updateList();


    mGeneratepas.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPassword = mPasswordGenerator.generateSessionKey(8);
            mPasswordView.setText(mPassword);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final EditText passdescEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add Password to List")
                    .setMessage("Saving Password:  " + mPassword)
                    .setView(passdescEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String password = String.valueOf(mPassword);
                            String passdesc = String.valueOf(passdescEditText.getText());
                            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put (PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSWORD, password);
                            values.put (PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASS_DESC, passdesc);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict(PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            db.close();
                            updateList();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}



private void updateList(){
       ArrayList<String> tasklist = new ArrayList<>();
       SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.query( PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.TABLE, new String[]{PasswordContract.PasswordEntry._ID, PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSWORD, PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASS_DESC},
               null, null, null, null, null);
       while (cursor.moveToNext()){
           int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSWORD);
           tasklist.add(cursor.getString(idx));
       }

       if (mAdapter == null){
           mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                   R.layout.item_password,
                   R.id.password,
                   tasklist);
           mPasswordListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       }else{
           mAdapter.clear();
           mAdapter.addAll(tasklist);
           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
       cursor.close();
       db.close();
```

here is the sample image:

[image: here is a sample image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to adapt your tasklist so it contains objects that have 2 strings fields for storing the passwords and their associated description.
For example :

```
class PasswordItem {
    String password;
    String description;
    PasswordItem(String password, String description){
        this.password = password;
        this.description= description;
}
```

Then you fill your tasklist with it :

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSWORD));
    String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASS_DESC));
    tasklist.add(new PasswordItem(password,description));
   }
```

After, for your mAdapter field, you need to extend the ArrayAdapter class and override its getView(int, View, ViewGroup) method to return the type of custom view that you want (this method will be call for producing each row of your ListView).

For example :

```
@override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_password, parent, false);
    }

    TextView passwordView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password);
    TextView passwordDescriptionView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description); // Use the id your chose for the password description view

    // We are extracting the PasswordItem at the right 'position' from the tasklist
    PasswordItem passwordItem = getItem(position);

    // Now can set the texts for each view
    passwordView.setText(passwordItem.password);
    passwordDescriptionView.setText(passwordItem.description);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am working on it Olivier. Let me see if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here :

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
               R.layout.item_password,
               R.id.password,
               tasklist);
```

here you are assigning id "R.id.password" to the adapter. So the adapter will set text in the id which you have given. So your password description wont be able to get anything. For description to work you need to make custom adapter.